# Stripe webhook does not send event with php

Tags: php, strip

I am working with the Stripe payments gateway in PHP. I've set up webhooks in account settings and sent a test webhook, but I don't get any events in my [webhook file](http://dev.artoonsolutions.com/Stripe/webhook.php):

```
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_hxdlbNUxlCUVK6V8p5nbxl8G"); 
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);
$event_id = $event_json->id;
echo $event_id;
```

Comment: Try avoiding putting @ before function names. You wont know if there is an error there. One thing I did when I was programming webhooks was to redirect the output buffer to a file so I could read the output. Use ob_start and ob_end_flush . This way you'll know what is exactly going on... meanwhile you could also do a var_dump on your body to know what you really received.